# How implement material design with constraint layout?

Tags: android, material-design, android-constraintlayout

recently i was updated my android studio to 2.2 stable version and created a new project for experiencing constraint layout.
After a while i noticed that constraint layout not working with material design support library. for example i don't know how to implement layout_behavior for recycler view! or float action button not going top when snack bar show.

So my question is **how implement material design features with constraint layout**?!!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working with material design support library"?

Comment: constraint layout is coming for remove nested hierarchy and easier layout editing. for this reason it's not logical to add coordinator layout to it. because after that we can't use constraint layout features and attributes in coordinator layout childs!

Comment: `ConstraintLayout` is not meant to replace `CoordinatorLayout`. If you want the behaviors of `CoordinatorLayout`, use `CoordinatorLayout`. `ConstraintLayout` is used to flatten `View` hierarchies. You don't need to use it everywhere, nor is it meant to be used everywhere.